# Using typescript ReturnType with keyof and iterated keys of generic type

Tags: typescript, return-type, keyof

I am trying to loop through functions in an object and get their return type to do some filtering as follow:

```
 export const StorageActions = {
      addFile: () => ({ type: 'ADD_FILE' }),
      deleteFile: () => {
        return () => {
          return null;
        };
      },
    };

type StorageActionsTypes = typeof StorageActions;

type ValidFunctions<T> = Pick<T, {
  [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[K]> extends { type: any } ? K : never;
}[keyof T]>;

type functions = ValidFunctions<StorageActionsTypes>;
```

the above code will show the following error:

*Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any[]) => any'.*

[image]

As error described, ReturnType expects a function, is that correct? or am I missing something here?

how can I tell the ReturnType that I am passing a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify constraint that values of `T` inside `ValidFunctions` only can be functions:

```
type ValidFunctions<T extends { [key: string]: (...args: any[]) => any }> = ...
```